# Meaning of にあると？

Tags: grammar

I'm not sure what the last part of this sentence means:

世界をこのようなみじめな状態にした責任は我々にあると言われても仕方がない。*

"About our responsibility in putting the world in this miserable state, we (?) even if is said there is no way"

My grammar fails at にあると言われても, how does that work?

*This is from the FF7 movie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're breaking down the sentence a little wrong.

It breaks down more like:

[(世界をこのようなみじめな状態にした責任は)我々にある]と言われても仕方がない

which translates literally as

"It can't be helped if people say that [(the responsibility for putting the world in such a miserable state) lies with us]."

In other words, にあると isn't really a unit here.

The に is marking 我々 as the indirect object of ある, in the standard construction XはYにある "X is at/with Y". In this case X is 責任 (and the whole relative clause preceding it) and Y is 我々, so it means "the responsibility is with us".

And the と is quoting everything preceding it as the content of what "people are saying".

Hope that helps.

Comment: And then there was light! I don't think I would have ever parsed it correctly without your help.

Comment: Stative (existence) verbs cannot have objects, only action verbs can have objects. 我々に is a clear adverbial of "place" in this case. "place" can be not just a physical location but a conceptual container. The formula XはYにある clearly shows that Xは is a subject and Yに is adverbial

Answer (score 1):

「世界をこのようなみじめな状態にした責任は我々にある」、と　言われても　仕方がない。

When we are said that it's our responsibility to put the world into such a miserable state, we have no excuses.

If we are said, "the responsibility to put the world into such a miserable state exists on us," we have no excuses.

我々にある＝exists on us

と＝that

言われても＝if we are said